# How did the grace period start before the bounty is over?

Tags: support, bug, bounties, expired-bounty

I got this message in my inbox:

[image]

It says that 25 minutes ago my grace period for my bounty on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60417/241700) started

But I still had 16 minutes left:

[image]

How is this possible?

Comment: I'd rather get the notification *before* my grace period started than *after*. Those notifications are likely generated by a process that only runs "every so often" so it's not possible to notify you the exact moment it expires.

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely a bug here, here's my screenshots from today:

[image: bounty grace period]

[image: bounty not over]